# jquery ToolTip that works in an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of any JQUERY ToolTip plugins that work well in an iFrame? I tried qTIP and it's positioning is all off.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I managed to add jquery to that iframe.

just simply find the wollwing statement in the current ckeditor.js:

```
h.push('<link type="text/css" rel=stylesheet href="' + g + '">');
```

and add the following right after:

```
h.push("<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>");
```

I used http://jsbeautifier.org/ to unminify this so I could edit it easier.

Comment: The iFrame has a src="" and is from CKEDITOR. I'd have to dynamically, load JQUERY and the qTIP plugin in the iframe after it was loaded. How's that possible?

Comment: I think I might be confused about why you are using an iframe. are you using the iframe to show external content or you are using it as a layer behind something or etc?

Comment: I'm using an iFrame because I'm using CKEDITOR which uses an iFrame... I want in the CKEDITOR iframe to have a tooltip on certain text. Does that make sense?

Comment: i edited the answer nobosh. will give you update when i found out more